# Does Oracle NoSQL Database support range queries?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

Some of the applications my team is developing will need range queries.

Are the indexes BTree In Oracle NoSQL Database? In one of the docs, it mentions that it's a "ordered maps".

Does it mean that it can't support range queries?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Oracle NoSQL Database uses B-trees and supports range queries.